# How to access util class by classes in different packages in java?

Tags: java, package

Consider the following packages in the same component (multi layer application)

- com.app.feature1
- com.app.feature2

Both contain classes. Let's say `com.app.feature1` contains class `A` and `com.app.feature2` contains class `B`. Both need the same code for their tasks. Let's call it `doSomething()` and put it in a class called `C`.
If I put class `C` in a new package `com.app.util` and make it public, `A` and `B` can use `doSomething()`, but classes of higher components can use `C`'s `doSomething()` and I don't want that. The next modifier is package-private. `A` and `B` are not in the same package as `C`. So they cannot use `C`'s `doSomething()`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Would it make sense in your case for classes `A` and `B` to inherit from class `C`?

Comment: No, there a only 'stupid' classes in there (Mapper, and so on)

Comment: How is "mapper" a stupid class? Sounds like a class that is perfectly fine to use with inheritance.

Comment: It's not perfect, but you can make `doSomething` of class `C` public and write in the JavaDoc, that it isn't part of the public API and shouldn't be used.

Comment: And then people will still ignore the JavaDoc and use it. I don't know what `Mapper` has to do with what I asked, though. Is there a reason why classes `A` and `B` can not extend class `C`? Because from what OP has told us, I don't see one, and inheritance would solve the problem with none of the drawbacks of the other possibilities.

Comment: Ok than assume there is a Mapper class and a Converter class. You cant extend both. Moreover I dont want to overcomplicate things, so Im a friend of composition over inheritance

Comment: But why would you need to extend both, and how are those classes related to classes `A`, `B` and `C` in your example? `doSomething()` is only one method in one class, if all you want to do is use that method in other classes that are in a different package, just inherit from the class that has it. That said, if you prefer to compose insted of inheriting, you can probably implement a Composite pattern that solves your problem, it will just be more work than a simple `extends`.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry if I'm not understanding your problem correctly, but I'll try to propose a solution)

You can make an abstract class which both `A` and `B` (let's call it `AbstractSomething`) inherit the method `doSomething()` from, and then the class `C` in another package can have a method which accepts `AbstractSomething` and calls `doSomething()` inside of it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).